# ActivityManager: Foreground service started from background can not have location/camera/microphone access

Tags: android, android-service, android-permissions, android-location, android-11

When my app starts service from background there occurs log in the Logcat: `ActivityManager: Foreground service started from background can not have location/camera/microphone access`. And I am okay with that because it is known restriction in Android 11.

How to programmatically determine whether my foreground service has access to location in Android 11? I want to stop the service when it doesn't have access to location.

Helpful links:

- Source of `ActiveServices` class: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActiveServices.java#1365
- Source of `ServiceRecord` class: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ServiceRecord.java#144

Comment: Did you have answer?

Comment: @hungcuiga1 Yes. I use `AppOpsManager`.

Comment: I am using type mediaproject service.Do you use it? Can you post a more detailed answer? Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @hungcuiga1, can you please share your answer?

Comment: @RanjithSubramaniam i don't remember it and don't know what is problem of you but you can ask your question in stackoverflow and link it here for me.